# SQL Win authentication from Web application?

Tags: sql, sql-server, web-applications, windows-authentication

Is it possible to use MSSQL Windows authentication to connect from one server to another using web application? Both servers are in the same VPN.

Thanks,
Ile

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if Kerberos delegation is turned on:

[Building Secure ASP.NET Applications: Authentication, Authorization, and Secure Communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649207.aspx)

> Summary: Kerberos delegation allows
>   you to flow an authenticated identity
>   across multiple physical tiers of an
>   application to support downstream
>   authentication and authorization. This
>   How To shows you the configuration
>   steps required to make this work.